# Inequality. $\frac{1}{16}(a+b+c+d)^3 \geq abc+bcd+cda+dab$

Tags: inequality

I want to prove the following inequality :

> $$\frac{1}{16}(a+b+c+d)^3 \geq abc+bcd+cda+dab,  $$
>   $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}_{+} .$

In my book, at the answers chapter the author uses *AM* $\geq$ *GM*, but I haven't any idea how I can use that.

Thanks :)

Comment: The RHS $= abcd(\sum\frac{1}{a})$

Comment: The author did't give a complete answer. He suggested that I could resove this inequality using AM $\geq$ GM.

Comment: @Iuli: what is the book and the name of the author?

Comment: The name of the book is : Inequalities-Theorems-Techniques-and-Selected-Problems and the name of the author is Zdravko-Cvetkovski. If you don't have this book I can send you. This inequality you can find in exercise 113, in the last part of the proof.

Comment: @Iuli: I know the book and it's worth to have it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Also notice that:

$$(a+b+c+d)^3 - 16(abc+abd+acd+bcd) = (a+b+c+d)(a+b-c-d)^2 + 4(c-d)^2(a+b) + 4(a-b)^2(c+d) \ge 0$$
Or
$$(a+b)[(a+b-c-d)^2 + 4(c-d)^2] + (c+d)[(a+b-c-d)^2 + 4(a-b)^2]\ge0$$

This way is suggested by a friend of mine.

Comment: Please, can you give me a more conclusive answer. Thank :)

Comment: Ok :) I will wait. Thanks

Comment: In the first suggestion, terms are either squared terms, and therefore positive, or involve adding together positive numbers, therefore positive.

Comment: This solution is ridiculously nice... (+1)

Answer (score 5):

You need to show that 
$$(a + b + c + d)^3 - 16(abc + bcd + cda + dab) \geq 0$$ 
It suffices to show this on any set of the form $0 \leq a,b,c,d \leq N$. By calculus (the "extreme value theorem") the function $(a + b + c + d)^3 - 16(abc + bcd + cda + dab)$ achieves its minimum at some $(a,b,c,d)$ in the set $0 \leq a,b,c,d \leq N$. I claim that this minimum has to occur when $a = b = c = d$.

Write $$(a + b + c + d)^3 - 16(abc + bcd + cda + dab) = (a + b + c + d)^3 - 16(a + b)cd - 16(c + d)ab$$ 
Note that by AM-GM, we have $16(c + d)ab \leq 16(c + d)({a + b \over 2})^2$. If we had $a \neq b$, we could replace $a$ and $b$ by ${a + b \over 2}$, leaving $c$ and $d$ constant, and we'd get a smaller value. So since $(a,b,c,d)$ is the minimum, this can't happen and we conclude that $a = b$. For similar reasons $c = d$, reversing the roles of the terms $16(a + b)cd$ and $16(c + d)ab$

Next, write $$(a + b + c + d)^3 - 16(abc + bcd + cda + dab) = (a + b + c + d)^3 - 16(b + d)ac - 16 (a + c)bd$$ Then arguing like above gives $b = d$ and $a = c$. Combining the above gives $a = b = c = d$, whereupon $(a + b + c + d)^3 - 16(abc + bcd + cda + dab) = (4a)^3 - 16(4a^3) = 0$. Since this is the minimum, the expression $(a + b + c + d)^3 - 16(abc + bcd + cda + dab)$ is nonnegative as needed.

Answer (score 5):

I posted this inequality on http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/ and I received a nice answer. This answer can be checked on the following link : http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=494463 .

Comment: Oh. A brilliant way! It wasn't that hard at all. I went for a while that way, but then I dropped it. I don't remember why. :-)

Comment: Yes, it is a nice solution. Yesterday I told you about that exercise from that book - now I need to find a solution for that inequality using Cauchy-Schwarz. Can you help me, please? I will post the inquality immediately . Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

This is a version of [Maclaurin's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality). We have
$$S_1=\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$$
$$S_3=\frac{abc+bcd+cda+dab}{4}$$

and so
$$S_1 \geqslant (S_3)^{\frac13}$$
gives the required result.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Zarrax, it suffices to show that
$$(a + b + c + d)^3 - 16(abc + bcd + cda + dab) = 4 \sum_{\mathrm{sym}}a^3 + 36 \sum_{\mathrm{sym}} a^2 b - 40 \sum_{\mathrm{sym}}abc$$
is nonnegative for all $a, b, c, d \ge 0$. Here I use the notation $\sum_{\mathrm{sym}}f(a,b ,c, d) := (1/4!) \sum_{\pi \in S_4} f(\pi(a), \pi(b), \pi(c), \pi(d))$ as $\pi$ ranges over all permutations of $\{a, b, c, d\}$.

But by AM-GM, $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \ge 3 abc$ so that $\sum_{\mathrm{sym}}(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) \ge 3 \sum_{\mathrm{sym}}abc$ or just $\sum_{\mathrm{sym}} a^3 \ge \sum_{\mathrm{sym}} abc$. Similarly, AM-GM also gives $a^2 b + a^2 c + b^2 a + b^2 c + c^2 a + c^2 b \ge 6 abc$, so that $\sum_{\mathrm{sym}} a^2 b \ge \sum_{\mathrm{sym}} abc$. Thus
$$4 \sum_{\mathrm{sym}}a^3 + 36 \sum_{\mathrm{sym}} a^2 b - 40 \sum_{\mathrm{sym}}abc
= 4 \left(\sum_{\mathrm{sym}}a^3  - \sum_{\mathrm{sym}}abc\right) + 36 \left(\sum_{\mathrm{sym}} a^2 b - \sum_{\mathrm{sym}}abc\right) \ge 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Solution by pure AM-GM:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{16}(a+b+c+d)^3 \ge abc + bcd + cda + dab \\ \iff (a+b+c+d)^3 \ge 16\cdot \sum_{\text{cyc}} abc \\ \iff\sum_{\text{cyc}}(a^3 + 3a^2b + 3a^2c + 3a^2d + 6abc) \ge 16\cdot \sum_{\text{cyc}}abc \\ \iff \sum_{\text{cyc}}a^3 + \sum_{\text{cyc}} 3a^2(b+c+d) \ge 10\cdot \sum_{\text{cyc}}abc
\end{equation}

Where $\sum_{\text{cyc}} a^3 = a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3 \ge abc + bcd + cda + dab$ by AM-GM (take $\frac{a^3 + b^3 + c^3}{3} \ge abc$ and likewise for the other three terms). Hence, it suffices to prove that

\begin{equation}
    \sum_{\text{cyc}}3a^2(b+c+d) \ge 9\cdot \sum_{\text{cyc}}abc \\ \iff \sum_{\text{cyc}}a^2(b+c+d) \ge 3\cdot \sum_{\text{cyc}}abc
\end{equation}

Which is true by AM-GM:

\begin{equation}
    a^2b + b^2c + c^2a \ge 3abc \\
    b^2d + d^2c + c^2b \ge 3bcd \\
    c^2d + d^2a + a^2c \ge 3cda \\
    d^2b + b^2a + a^2d \ge 3dab
\end{equation}