# How do I prove thcd

Tags: inequality

It makes me think of means... The RHS Is like a geometric mean but the "divided by 4" annoyes me. The LHS is probably an arithmetic mean... Can they be combined?

Comment: This was answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184029/inequality-frac116abcd3-geq-abcbcdcdadab)

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$\sqrt{\frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}{4}}
=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}\cdot \sqrt{4\cdot\frac{1}{4^2}}\geq \frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\\\geq  \sqrt[3]{\frac{abc + abd + acd + bcd}{4}}$$
where in the last step we use 
[Inequality. $\frac{1}{16}(a+b+c+d)^3 \geq abc+bcd+cda+dab$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184029/inequality-frac116abcd3-geq-abcbcdcdadab?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: The first inequality $\sqrt{\frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}{4}} \geq \frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$, in addition to being a special case of CS, actually has its own name: The quadratic mean-arithmetic mean inequality.