# Prove $\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{4}}\geq\sqrt[3]{\frac{abc+abd+acd+bcd}{4}}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

For real numbers $a, b, c, d >0$ I have to prove that  $$\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{4}}\geq\sqrt[3]{\frac{abc+abd+acd+bcd}{4}}$$ always holds. I tried using the mean inequalities for multiple numbers but I always get in trouble with the different orders of the two roots. And in case I make an estimate that can handle the orders of the roots, it is too strong. Can anyone help?

Comment: i have an ugly proof, powring by $6$, setting $$b=a+u,c=a+u+v,d=a+u+v+w$$ and after the polynomial in $$a,u,v,w$$ is positive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [this inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184029/inequality-frac116abcd3-geq-abcbcdcdadab?rq=1):

$\frac{1}{16}(a+b+c+d)^3 \geq abc+bcd+cda+dab$ equivalent $\frac{1}{4}(a+b+c+d) \geq \sqrt[3]{\frac{abc+abd+acd+bcd}{4}}$ Now just prove$\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{4}}\geq \frac{1}{4}(a+b+c+d)$ equivalent $4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)\geq (a+b+c+d)^2$ equivalent $3(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)\geq 2(ab+ac+ad+ bc + bd + cd)$ equivalent $(a-b)^2 + (a-c)^2 + (a-d)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (b-d)^2  + (c-d)^2 \ge 0$

Comment: Proving $\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{4}}\geq \frac{1}{4}(a+b+c+d)$ then is really easy since this is just the inequality between the quadratic and the arithmetic mean.

Comment: @mxian See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Since 
$$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{4}\geq\frac{ab+ac+bc+ad+bd+cd}{6}$$
it's just
$$(a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(a-d)^2+(b-c)^2+(b-d)^2+(c-d)^2\geq0,$$ it's enough to prove that
$$\sqrt{\frac{ab+ac+bc+ad+bd+cd}{6}}\geq\sqrt[3]{\frac{abc+abd+acd+bcd}{4}},$$
which I proved here:
[How to prove this inequality $\sqrt{\frac{ab+bc+cd+da+ac+bd}{6}}\geq \sqrt[3]{{\frac{abc+bcd+cda+dab}{4}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197955)