Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive real numbers. Prove that $(a+b+c+d)^3 \geq 16(abc+abd+acd+bcd)$
I am attempting to show that for positive real numbers $a,b,c,d$, the following inequality holds:
$$
\frac{a}{\sqrt{bc+bd+cd}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{ac+ad+cd}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{ab+ad+bd}}+\frac{d}{\sqrt{ab+ac+bc}} \geq \frac{4\sqrt{3}}{3}.
$$
I have used Holder's inequality in the following way (using cyclic notation for sums):
$$
\begin{align}
\big(\sum\frac{a}{\sqrt{bc+bd+cd}}\big)^2 \sum a(bc+bd+cd) &= \big(\sum\frac{a}{\sqrt{bc+bd+cd}}\big)\big(\sum\frac{a}{\sqrt{bc+bd+cd}}\big)\sum a(bc+bd+cd) \\
&\geq \big(\sum (a^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}\big)^3 = \big(\sum a\big)^3
\end{align}
$$
Also, we see that $\sum a(bc+bd+cd)$ can be rewritten in the following way:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum a(bc+bd+cd) &= a(bc+bd+cd)+b(ac+ad+cd)+c(ab+ad+bd)+d(ab+ac+bc) \\
&= 3(abc+abd+acd+bcd) \\
&= 3 \sum abc \\
\end{align} 
$$
Thus, proving the original inequality is equivalent to proving that
$$
\big(\sum a\big)^3 \geq 16 \sum abc \iff (a+b+c+d)^3 \geq 16(abc+abd+acd+bcd)
$$
Ironically, this seems like a much easier inequality to show, but for some reason I just can't make it work (it is definitely true though). Any help please? I've tried AM-GM ideas and just got that both sides have the same lower bound. I've tried more Holder ideas but haven't got anything to work.

You may want to get familiar with Maclaurin's inequality.

Check out other options at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184029/inequality-frac116abcd3-geq-abcbcdcdadab
